# maven multimodule project-Update POM parent section in selected projects

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I am creating multimodule project using maven in eclipse.After configuring parent in that configuration tab,to add modules I have selected Add and selected the modules to be added and I have checked the 'Update POM parent section in selected projects'.But it doesnot include the parent information in the selected modules.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that such a feature exists, but you can do it by your own, with more reliability adding those lines to your parent pom :

#### parent pom.xml

Here put your modules configuration

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.company.bla.bla</groupId>
    <artifactId>you-parent-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <modules>
         <module>module-child-1</module>
          <module>module-child-2</module>
    </modules>
```

#### childs pom.xml

Here put you parent reference and ommit version

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.company.bla.bla</groupId>
        <artifactId>you-parent-artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>child-1</artifactId>
```

More information here : http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html